# What is the right way to use OR and AND in appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

Is this the right way to write OR condition to combine the 2 if statements into 1?

```
if (activeSheet.getName() == ("2 Grade" || "3 Grade") && Cell.getRow() >= 53 && Cell.getColumn() >= 9 && Cell.getRow() <= 57 && Cell.getColumn() <= 13) {
     supplierSeal2G.copyTo(supplierSeal2GData, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
     surveyorSeal2G.copyTo(surveyorSeal2GData, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
     remarks2G.copyTo(remarks2GData, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `sheetName` is declared and used for the if statement.

#### From:

```
if (activeSheet.getName() == ("2 Grade" || "3 Grade") && Cell.getRow() >= 53 && Cell.getColumn() >= 9 && Cell.getRow() <= 57 && Cell.getColumn() <= 13) {
```

#### To:

```
var sheetName = activeSheet.getName();
if ((sheetName == "2 Grade" || sheetName == "3 Grade") && Cell.getRow() >= 53 && Cell.getColumn() >= 9 && Cell.getRow() <= 57 && Cell.getColumn() <= 13) {
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `["2 Grade", "3 Grade"]` is prepared as an array and used for the if statement with `indexOf()`.

#### From:

```
if (activeSheet.getName() == ("2 Grade" || "3 Grade") && Cell.getRow() >= 53 && Cell.getColumn() >= 9 && Cell.getRow() <= 57 && Cell.getColumn() <= 13) {
```

#### To:

```
var sheetNames = ["2 Grade", "3 Grade"];
if (sheetNames.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) > -1 && Cell.getRow() >= 53 && Cell.getColumn() >= 9 && Cell.getRow() <= 57 && Cell.getColumn() <= 13) {
```

### References:

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.